# How to develop a plan for your javascript

Tags: javascript

my exposure to web development has primarily, the front end HTML, CSS with some JQuery thrown in for simple animations.

However I am working on a pretty big project right now for work. This will include a ton of javascript functions involving, Object calls, AJAX calls and so forth.

I have a good grasp of functions and all that, but as development is continuing, I am worried about keeping all of the calls organized and flowing efficiently.

So I am curious about what subjects are out there to help effectively plan out something like this, it doesn't necessarily have to be about Javascript, but planning any sort of project to ensure that your code is easily manageable, and everything is in it's proper place.

This is a new type of development for me, coming from HTML and CSS, and I want to make sure that the foundation of this project is rock solid.

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library in that project?

Comment: Yes, we are currently using JQuery, and I would like ensure that everything doesn't get mashed together, and there is some order of things.

Comment: UML, vars and function naming conventions? ;)

Comment: Object orientated concepts in javascript...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some links that might help get you started based on JavaScript

**jQuery:** (since you stated jQuery as a familiarity)

[Using Inheritance Pattern](http://alexsexton.com/?p=51)

[jQuery to large application developement](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/11/15/from-jquery-to-large-applications/)

**MVC Pattern:**

[JavascripMVC](http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-jquery-needs-javascriptmvc)

[MVC Pattern with JavaScript](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-mvc/)

**[Videos]** ( from the reminder in the comments below )

[YUI Theater](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/)

**[Misc]**

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/)

[Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/)

[Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I stumbled across this video yesterday and was wondering if this was also a good resource? http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=zakas-architecture

Comment: YES! YUI Theater is definitely a good resource. I can't believe I forgot to add that to the list. It's usually the top spot I always refer folks to for good web related videos. Thanks for the reminder! :P